# How to get the google search results in php?

Tags: php, curl

I'm using the following php script to get search results from Google.

```
$useragent = "Opera/9.80 (J2ME/MIDP; Opera Mini/4.2.14912/870; U; id) Presto/2.4.15";
$ch = curl_init ("");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site:" . urlencode($url));
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent); // set user agent
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
return $output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

but i receives google captcha.

so is there any ways to avoid the captcha so i can get the results?

Comment: Yes, you stop violating google's TOS and use their APIs to get results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the official API such as this:

[Google Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/)

Comment: What if you use proxies?